# Calendar not showing Google events

Tags: ubuntu-touch, m10

I have successfully set up my Google account andcan see emails in both the gmail and decko apps. In the calendar app I see the calendar listed alonside 'personal' but no events are being synched.

Furthermore events created on my m10 tablet do not appear in the Google calendar online.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that Calendar synchronization is activated in System Settings -> Online Accounts.

[image]

Then open the Calendar application -> Calendar Settings and check what shall be synchronized.

[image]

The screenshots are showing Online Accounts and the Calendar application in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks @cl-netbox that gave me the tip I needed: I had checked the second screenshot you included but not found the first one: system settings > me@gmail.com > sync page. I guess it's not great usability to have the first without including a link that the second is also needed.